# dict.setdefault: only consume iterator if item did not exist

Tags: python

Some fragment of a code looks like this (this is a stripped down version of the problem):

```
y = dict()
it = iter([1,2,3])

y.setdefault(23, next(it))
y.setdefault(42, next(it))
y.setdefault(42, next(it))
y.setdefault(1337, next(it))  # throws StopIteration

# The result should look like this:
# {23: 1, 42: 2, 1337: 3}
```

Basically, there is some iterator and I would like to fill a dictionary using `setdefault` with the next value in that iterator but only if the value did not exist in the dictionary before. Obviously in this case it fails because `next()` is called 4 times, even though there are only 3 unique values to put into the dict.

One solution could be to simply write a function or a class that does the check:

```
def setdefault(d, k, v):
    if k in d:
        return d[k]
    return d.setdefault(k, next(v))
```

or

```
class mydict(dict):
    def it_setdefault(self, k, i):
        if k in self:
            return self[k]
        return self.setdefault(k, next(i))
```

However, I wonder if there is something like this already available for dictionaries?

Comment: Nope, arguments are evaluated before functions/methods are called, so the dict cannot do anything about the iterator being consumed. Your solution is fine.

Comment: @timgeb "fine" if they're not allowed to use defaultdict.

Comment: `collections.defaultdict(lambda: next(it))`?

Comment: @MechanicPig Or without the wrapper: `defaultdict(it.__next__)`.

Comment: well, the `defaultdict` solves it flawlessly!

Comment: For that example use case you could also deduplicaze the keys in advance, i.e., `dict(zip(dict.fromkeys([23,42,42,1337]), [1,2,3]))`. (But neither that nor defaultdict fit the question...)

Comment: @KellyBundy I agree, good idea. Should post it as an answer.